# Не могу перезаписать django admin template

Tags: python, django, django-admin

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

Вроде бы все правильно прописал

Создаю файл в `{ BASE_DIR }/templates/admin/base_site.html`, пытаюсь что-либо изменить, только ничего не получается

Comment: 1. Зачем вы указываете `TEMPLATE_DIRS`, если у вас `'DIRS'` такой же? 2. Какая у вас структура папок? Должна быть такая: 

имя_проекта (BASE_DIR) ->  templates/ -> admin/

Comment: потому что изначально не работало, посмотрел, думал добавлю исправиться. И по структуре ничего не нарушал, добавлял в корневую папку